# Unity Package Error "the type of namespace could not be found"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces, assets

Hi i'm using unity package called "Movement Animset Pro v1.693.unitypackage" for unity character moving when i import package in unity all thins goes fine except the script file it gives me errors all over the code i'm using the last unity version and here is the code

// (c) Copyright HutongGames, LLC 2010-2011. All rights reserved.

```
    using UnityEngine;

    namespace HutongGames.PlayMaker.Actions
    {


[ActionCategory(ActionCategory.Transform)]
[Tooltip("Moves a Game Object towards a Target. Optionally sends an event when successful. Optionally set when to update, during regular update, lateUpdate or FixedUpdate. The Target can be specified as a Game Object or a world Position. If you specify both, then the Position is used as a local offset from the Object's Position.")]
public class MoveTowards2 : FsmStateAction
{
    public enum UpdateType {Update,LateUpdate,FixedUpdate};

    [RequiredField]
    public FsmOwnerDefault gameObject;

    public FsmGameObject targetObject;

    public FsmVector3 targetPosition;

    public FsmBool ignoreVertical;

    [HasFloatSlider(0, 20)]
    public FsmFloat maxSpeed;

    [HasFloatSlider(0, 5)]
    public FsmFloat finishDistance;

    public FsmEvent finishEvent;

    public UpdateType updateType;


    public override void Reset()
    {
        gameObject = null;
        targetObject = null;
        maxSpeed = 10f;
        finishDistance = 1f;
        finishEvent = null;
        updateType = UpdateType.Update;
    }

    public override void OnUpdate()
    {
        if (updateType == UpdateType.Update)
        {
            DoMoveTowards();
        }
    }

    public override void OnLateUpdate()
    {
        if (updateType == UpdateType.LateUpdate)
        {
            DoMoveTowards();
        }
    }

    public override void OnFixedUpdate()
    {
        //if (updateType == UpdateType.FixedUpdate)
        //{
            DoMoveTowards();
        //}
    }

    void DoMoveTowards()
    {
        var go = Fsm.GetOwnerDefaultTarget(gameObject);
        if (go == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var goTarget = targetObject.Value;
        if (goTarget == null && targetPosition.IsNone)
        {
            return;
        }

        Vector3 targetPos;
        if (goTarget != null)
        {
            targetPos = !targetPosition.IsNone ? 
                goTarget.transform.TransformPoint(targetPosition.Value) : 
                goTarget.transform.position;
        }
        else
        {
            targetPos = targetPosition.Value;
        }

        if (ignoreVertical.Value)
        {
            targetPos.y = go.transform.position.y;
        }

        go.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(go.transform.position, targetPos, maxSpeed.Value * Time.deltaTime);

        var distance = (go.transform.position - targetPos).magnitude;
        if (distance < finishDistance.Value)
        {
            Fsm.Event(finishEvent);
            Finish();
        }
    }

}
}
```

and here is the errors

```
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(11,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FsmStateAction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(9,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionCategoryAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(9,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionCategory' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(9,18): error CS0103: The name 'ActionCategory' does not exist in the current context
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(10,3): error CS0592: Attribute 'Tooltip' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field' declarations.
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(35,24): error CS0115: 'MoveTowards2.Reset()': no suitable method found to override
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(45,24): error CS0115: 'MoveTowards2.OnUpdate()': no suitable method found to override
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(53,24): error CS0115: 'MoveTowards2.OnLateUpdate()': no suitable method found to override
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(61,24): error CS0115: 'MoveTowards2.OnFixedUpdate()': no suitable method found to override
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(15,4): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RequiredFieldAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(15,4): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RequiredField' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(16,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FsmOwnerDefault' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(18,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FsmGameObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(20,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FsmVector3' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(22,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FsmBool' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(24,4): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HasFloatSliderAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(24,4): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HasFloatSlider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(25,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FsmFloat' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(27,4): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HasFloatSliderAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(27,4): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HasFloatSlider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(28,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FsmFloat' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\MovementAnimsetPro\PlayMakerAdditionalActions\PlayMaker\Actions\MoveTowards2.cs(30,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FsmEvent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and there is 5 anothe scripts with the same errors .. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says the program doesn't find the names like 'FsmStateAction', look into your assets for that name and find the script that contains it, then put the namespace of the script at the top of your code like:

```
using someNamespace;
```

I can see that you have some errors of override, you cannot override this methods if they aren't virtual, check the code of the package before you make your own.